# What is the opposite of outline:none in css?

Tags: javascript, css

Using a timeout to fix a animation jitter, I am trying ot toggle outline in javascript.  After the animations has been completed i want to reset the outline to be back to normal...

> I thought `inherit` but not working :c.

```
modalEl.style.outline = "none";    
modalEl.style.outline = "inherit";
```

Comment: a quick chrome dev tool search said `initial`

Comment: You can always remove an inline style property by setting it empty, i.e. `modalEl.style.outline = "";`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline

Comment: it is totally a blank string.  Teemu wanan put the answer and I'll mark correct.  Believe it or not this isnt a question on stack.

Comment: `invert none medium` This is the `initial` value of `outline` property.

Comment: To give an accurate answer, there's not enough information in the post. If you've an inline style `outline:some_value` set before setting it empty, setting it empty won't bring back the previous value, rather it just removes the rule. Notice, that inline styles override the stylesheet rules, and if an inline style is removed, the original stylesheet rule (from browser's default stylesheet(= initial) too, if any stylesheet is not included) is applied.

Comment: What does “back to normal” mean in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the documentation to it on MDN,

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline

To reset it,

```
modalEl.style.outline = "initial";
```

Or as already said by Teemu, use empty string to remove this property from the element. The empty string would simply just remove the CSS property from the element at all.

Comment: Since this is equivalent to `modalEl.style.outline = "invert none medium"`, how can it be the opposite of `none`?

Comment: This did not work for me. I'd like to be able to override "none" with a rule that sets the outline back to its default without any details about what the outline should look like.

Comment: @zero_cool, you can see if anything is trying to override the behavior using `!important`.